# Mongoose $ project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose `4.0.x`, I need to execute the following (working) MongoDB query:

```
db.bookings.find(
  {
    user: ObjectId("10"), // I replaced the real ID
    'flights.busy.from': {$gte: ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00Z")},
    'flights.busy.to': {$lte: ISODate("2015-04-01T23:59:00Z")}
  },
  {
    'flights.$': 1 // This is what I don't know to replicate
  }
).pretty()
```

The [Mongoose `find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) operator does not accept a [`projection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) operator, like the [MongoDB `find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) one does.

How can I replicate the above query in Mongoose? Filtering the array once the query is returned is a solution I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the docs for [`Model.find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), not `Query.find`.  The second parameter can be used for field selection:

```
MyModel.find(
  {
    user: ObjectId("10"), // I replaced the real ID
    'flights.busy.from': {$gte: ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00Z")},
    'flights.busy.to': {$lte: ISODate("2015-04-01T23:59:00Z")}
  },
  'flights.$'
).exec(function(err, docs) {...});
```

Comment: I though filed selection was executed afterwards the query, not as a projection, furthermore the documentation never mentions the `$` operator in the [`Query.select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) API (the one you are referred to in the `Model.find` API)

Comment: No, the field selection happens server-side as part of the query.  The docs likely don't mention `$` because Mongoose doesn't interpret that in any way because it _is_ handled server-side.  Call `mongoose.set('debug', true);` in your startup code to see that actual queries that get sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination

Comment: You can chain the select statement too if you're into that sort of thing. `MyModel.find({...}).select('flights.$').exec(function(err, docs) {...})`